# Node.js apps and Drupal Nginx Conflict

Tags: node.js, drupal, nginx

I'm currently running two Ghost Node.js blogs on my VPS. They were working fine when I used proxy_pass in their respective .conf files.

For example:

`proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2468;`

I have another blog on port 2368. But when I introduced a Drupal site onto my VPS I assumed that it would work fine because my .conf setting file was reading a path and URL.

Like this:

`server_name example.com;`

`root /var/www/example;`

What happens is when I go to the 3 domains that are pointing at my server, they all display the Drupal site. I can't understand why it's overriding the settings. All three sites have separate config exampledomain.conf Nginx files.

Does anyone have any ideas? I've been trying to work this out for days now!

**DRUPAL SERVER BLOCK 1**

```
    server {
    server_name leafylane.com;
    root /var/www/leafylane; ## <-- Your only path reference.
    # Enable compression, this will help if you have for instance advagg‎ module
    # by serving Gzip versions of the files.
    gzip_static on;
    location = /favicon.ico {
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
    }
    location = /robots.txt {
            allow all;
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
    }
    # This matters if you use drush prior to 5.x
    # After 5.x backups are stored outside the Drupal install.
    #location = /backup {
    #        deny all;
    #}
    # Very rarely should these ever be accessed outside of your lan
    location ~* \.(txt|log)$ {
            allow 192.168.0.0/16;
            deny all;
    }
    location ~ \..*/.*\.php$ {
            return 403;
    }
    # No no for private
    location ~ ^/sites/.*/private/ {
            return 403;
    }
    # Block access to "hidden" files and directories whose names begin with a
    # period. This includes directories used by version control systems such
    # as Subversion or Git to store control files.
    location ~ (^|/)\. {
            return 403;
    }
    location / {
            # This is cool because no php is touched for static content
            try_files $uri @rewrite;
    }
    location @rewrite {
            # You have 2 options here
            # For D7 and above:
            # Clean URLs are handled in drupal_environment_initialize().
            rewrite ^ /index.php;
            # For Drupal 6 and bwlow:
            # Some modules enforce no slash (/) at the end of the URL
            # Else this rewrite block wouldn't be needed (GlobalRedirect)
            #rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            #NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    }
    # Fighting with Styles? This little gem is amazing.
    # This is for D6
    #location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/imagecache/ {
    # This is for D7 and D8
    location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/styles/ {
            try_files $uri @rewrite;
    }
    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
            expires max;
            log_not_found off;
    }
    }
```

**SERVER BLOCK 2**

```
    server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:8080;
    server_name tomcusack.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/tomcusack.com.log;
    location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2368;
    proxy_redirect off;
    }
    }
    server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:8080;
    server_name www.tomcusack.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/tomcusack.com.log;
    location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2368;
    proxy_redirect off;
    }
    }
```

**SERVER BLOCK 3**

```
    server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:8080;
    server_name sancho-panza.co.uk;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/sancho-panza.co.uk.log;
    location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2468;
    proxy_redirect off;
    }
    }
    server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:8080;
    server_name www.sancho-panza.co.uk;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/sancho-panza.co.uk.log;
    location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2468;
    proxy_redirect off;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post all 3 server blocks? Are you explicitly setting the server name (including www) for each one?

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks for the post. I've added all three blocks to my question! What do you make of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot. I identified quite a few issues with your original server blocks, and made some assumptions about what you are trying to do. Let me know if i'm mistaken.

You have a Drupal installation, and two Ghost blogs. All of which you wish to serve on port 80 from your VPS machine based on which URL is requested. Each of which need to accept both www and non-www requests.

Your original server blocks had a few mistakes, such as using multiple blocks for www/non-www which I have simplified. Note that you only need to separate these into different blocks if you plan on handling the www differently from non-www.

As a final note, make sure that you use "sudo nginx -s reload" to reload the config files, as that will spit out more detailed debugging information if you have any syntax errors

```
server  {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
        server_name leafylane.com www.leafylane.com;
        root /var/www/leafylane; 
        gzip_static on;
        location = /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }
        location = /robots.txt {
                allow all;
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }
        location ~* \.(txt|log)$ {
                allow 192.168.0.0/16;
                deny all;
        }
        location ~ \..*/.*\.php$ {
                return 403;
        }
        location ~ ^/sites/.*/private/ {
                return 403;
        }
        location ~ (^|/)\. {
                return 403;
        }
        location / {
                try_files $uri @rewrite;
        }
        location @rewrite {
                rewrite ^ /index.php;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
                fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        }
        location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/styles/ {
                try_files $uri @rewrite;
        }
        location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
        }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name tomcusack.com www.tomcusack.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/tomcusack.com.log;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2368;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

} 

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name sancho-panza.co.uk www.sancho-panza.co.uk;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/sancho-panza.co.uk.log;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2468;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Alex, Thank you so much for your help. I'll give it a shot now. Just a quick, rather important, omission I've failed to mention is that I've got Varnish sitting at the front listening to port 80 passing to port 8080.

Comment: Ah ok, then just simply replace the port 80 assignments with 8080

Comment: How strange! Nginx complained about having a duplicate 8080 port being listed (in the first block), regarding the ipv6. I changed that to port 8081 to reload successfully.

It's now causing a bad gateway with that configuration. But it **IS** diverting the traffic accordingly.

Comment: It works! Wow - I really can't thank you enough! I was wondering whether you could spend 5 minutes explaining what you changed and why? I'd really like to learn from this to help others myself and for the future. Thanks Alex!

Comment: Sure thing. Like I said above, you had a few syntax errors and redundancies with your server blocks. As a result, those blocks were being ignored completely by nginx and it was serving up the only working one (leafylane.com) as the default for every domain. 

Take for instance, `server_name sancho-panza.co.uk www.sancho-panza.co.uk;`

I combined the two server blocks you had setup for www/non-www into a single line. I'm not sure if the way you had it would work or not but this is the standard for such things. Also, prepending your port declarations (i.e. 0.0.0.0:8080) is unnecessary.